# QWidget - set border from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have QWidget instance (with other QWidgets inside) in Qt 5.8 and I want to set some border around it. Is there some way to do this from C++ without affecting any of it's children and their settings and positions?

I don't want to use stylesheets and it needs to work with any system style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `QFrame` which inherits `QWidget`.

Set `Frame::Shape` in the method below to `QFrame::Box`. This will produce borders around your Frame:

```
QFrame::setFrameShape(QFrame::Shape);
```

Use `setLineWidth` to set the line width:

```
QFrame::setLineWidth(int);
```